# using Interfaces and method onAttach(Fragments)

Tags: android, interface, android-activity, android-fragments

I know that its nob question but i cant understand what does the variable **`someEventListener`** assign?..
How can we compare activity with Interface **`onSomeEventListener`**) ?

```
 public interface onSomeEventListener {
    public void someEvent(String s);
  }

  onSomeEventListener someEventListener;

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
          someEventListener = (onSomeEventListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement onSomeEventListener");
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If an object implements a listener, it can be cast to another object with the listener type. In this case, we are casting the activity to the listener.

```
public class MyObject implements MyListener {

}

MyObject obj = new MyOBject();
MyListener listener = (MyListener)obj; // This is valid
```